# Laravel Forge, trying to deploy but get this error: Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-forge

I am trying to deploy my Laravel application on forge but when I go to view it on my server I am getting the following error, everything works perfectly on my local machine:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 150:
Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

I am assuming I need to do a composer update somewhere? I have tried adding it in the 'deploy script' and running it but no luck...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like it may have been a cache problem as I have just tried it again by adding the `composer update` to the deploy script and then deploying it and it is all working :)

```
cd /home/forge/default
git pull origin master
composer install
php artisan migrate --force
composer update <-- Add this onto the end
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a `composer update` (*extremely* slow) after a `composer install` unless your `composer.lock` file is not in your repository.

Comment: I just doubled checked and I do have a `composer.lock` file in my repo. It does not have anything it it saying that it requires that `HTML class` etc though, could this have been the problem?

Comment: Do a local `composer update` and make sure the `composer.lock` file is committed afterwards (L4 used to `.gitignore` it).